# Clearcase global search from all vobs

Tags: clearcase

Is there a some  sort of global search across all views and VOBS in ClearCase.

I need to find a file called "`aaa`", and I don't know  which  vob contains it.

Is there a way to find it?

Comment: To moderators: what the OP is asking is crystal clear (to anyone knowing ClearCase, that is)

Answer (score 3):

[`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm)  has a `–avobs` parameter to start with all the elements, branches, and versions in **all the VOBs mounted on the local host**.

So:

- make sure your VOBs are mounted ([`cleartool mount`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mount.htm))
- make your search in a dynamic view (any dynamic view: the mounted vobs will be accessible there)

That is:

```
cd m:\myview
# or
cd /views/myview
cleartool find -avobs -name "aaa"
```

If there is an element named "`aaa`" in one of the mounted vob, that query will find it.